# QGis not upgrading from 1.9.0. Ubuntu, Raring, using nghtly PPA

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, update

I'm currently running 1.9.0 on ubuntu raring, through the nightly ppas:

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian-nightly raring main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian-nightly raring main
```

But it doesn't update with software updater, even though I know there are more recent versions it should be pulling down. Can anyone think off-hand why that might be or what I could do to fix it?

I noticed that on the new qgis homepage, the nightly PPAs are not listed for raring... have they been discontinued for some reason, or temporarily broken?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: 6th September 2013 is the last nightly http://qgis.org/debian-nightly/dists/raring/

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I assume my ubuntu install my be earlier than that since it's 1.9 and my win7 install is 2.1 alpha, but i'll check when i next boot into ubuntu.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that for some reason the up-to-date QGis on ubuntu still had the 1.9.0 splash screen, whereas on Win7 it had the newer one. Odd.